# View C# compiled code for possible optimisation(branchless)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to see the compiled c# code in visual studio (when it is compiled to assembly/IL)?

I am looking at branchless programming and would like to compare how different functions compile for better optimisation. (Note: Im currently just using a stopwatch to time how long functions take to complete).

I havent been able to find info on this anywhere, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the generated IL (which can e.g. be done using ildasm) does not tell you much. Most of the optimizations are performed by the JIT Compiler when generating machine code for the target platform.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an online compiler/reviewer like SharpLab (https://sharplab.io/)

There are others out there as well, and I've never compared them head to head to see if they varied.

Comment: As Klaus Gütter has already pointed out most of the optimization is done during jitting, so you should choose `JIT ASM` at the **Results** drop down list to see what could a JIT compile from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BenchMark.Net`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to run your code.

It lets you decorate your code with a [`[DisassemblyDiagnoser]` attribute](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/diagnosers.html#sample-introdisassembly) which will output things like:

```
; .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.3110.0
05452718 BenchmarkDotNet.Samples.IntroDisassembly.Sum()
IL_0000: ldc.r8 0
IL_0009: stloc.0
0545271c d9ee            fldz
IL_000a: ldc.i4.0
IL_000b: stloc.1
IL_000c: br.s IL_0017
0545271e 33c0            xor     eax,eax
IL_000e: ldloc.0
IL_000f: ldloc.1
IL_0010: conv.r8
IL_0011: add
IL_0012: stloc.0
05452720 8945fc          mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
05452723 db45fc          fild    dword ptr [ebp-4]
05452726 dec1            faddp   st(1),st
IL_0013: ldloc.1
IL_0014: ldc.i4.1
IL_0015: add
IL_0016: stloc.1
05452728 40              inc     eax
IL_0017: ldloc.1
IL_0018: ldc.i4.s 64
IL_001a: blt.s IL_000e
05452729 83f840          cmp     eax,40h
0545272c 7cf2            jl      05452720
IL_001c: ldloc.0
IL_001d: ret
0545272e 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
```

As a bonus, BenchMark.Net provides a wealth of performance metrics for your code, and helps to prevent skew caused by warmup compilation and garbage collection (among other things). It's the canonical package to use if you are interested in measuring and comparing your code's performance.

As an example, this feature was used by Stephen Toub to [illustrate some of the improvements in the Jitter for .Net Core 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-5/).

Answer (score 0):

I use ReSharper for this, which allows you to do this directly from VisualStudio. Unless you are a student it's unfortunately rather pricey, because this is only a small functionality of it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Viewing_Intermediate_Language.html